# Determine location using IR transmitters and receiver

Tags: signal, signal-processing, infrared

Let's say I have multiple IR transmitters with known relative locations. Each transmitter emits a unique frequency. I also have an IR receiver in an unknown location surrounded by the transmitters. How can I determine the location of the receiver?

Comment: How far apart are these devices? How accurate do you want the location estimate to be? Indoors or outdoors? Do you have atomic clocks at each of the transmitters?

Comment: within a meter apart, indoors, doesnt have to be super accurate

Comment: Sorry, but "super accurate" really doesn't mean anything. How about those atomic clocks? Synchronized within 1ns of each other?

Comment: Measure the angle to each and triangulate. You will need a directional receiver. Tri-lateration via time of flight isn't feasible.

Comment: What terminology would you like when I have no metric? No atomic clock

Comment: You cannot design anything like this unless you have detailed specs with tolerances and acceptance criteria with a way to verify it,  Unfortunately, what you suggest is not possible with the method you suggested or anything similar as vague as it was.

Comment: If you can't quantify what you need...you "have no metric"...you can not create a suitable design.

Answer (score 0):

Decades ago, I built a logarithmic AC_coupled amplifier to handle 60KHz IR squarewaves detection. We could measure angles out to 10meters (that is, the NE567 tone decoder provided YES/NO behavior out to 10 meters), with just a 5 milliamp drive to the TX LED, and a standard TO-92 lense-atop-case phototransistor detector.

To handle a wide dynamic range input to receiver, the phototransistor was adaptively biased to null out sunlight and most of the 60Hz/120Hz of incandescents.
Modern electronics-ballast flourescents (with 80,000Hz photon switching) will be a problem for you.

The post-phototransistor amplifier was a bipolar common-emitter, biased with DC_low_pass feedback to about 4 volts (approx. 50% of the 9volt VDD). The AC feedback was (DC_blocked) 470Kohm in parallel with back-to-back diodes in series with 10Kohm and also in parallel with back-to-back diodes in series with 1Kohm.